# Switching values in spinner based on values in ArrayList

Tags: java, android

I have an Array list which is generated dynamically, it has a capacity to store 5 elements in all. Now this arraylist can contain 2,3,4,5,6 as elements at all. Sometimes some of these elements might be missing as it is generated dynamically. I want to switch positions in the Spinner based in the array list on a button click. How do I keep track of which element is displayed and move to next element?

For example in onCreate I detect the first element of the Arraylist if that is 2 I set

spin.setSelectedItem(aList.get(1));

The above sete my selection to 2 in the spinner.

on Button Click I want to switch to the next element in the list - The problem here is that the next element can be present or not I use the following check:
`if ((spin.getSelectedItemPosition()) < Integer.valueOf(pages.get(pages.size()-1)))`

But now how set Spinner value to the next element in the above if condition?

### EDIT

Currently I am doing something like:

```
int current = spin.getSelectedItemPosition();
int nextPos = (pages.indexOf(String.valueOf(current)))+1;
spin.setSelection(Integer.valueOf(pages.get(nextPos)));
```

where spin is my spinner and pages is the arraylist I have.

Comment: what about `spin.setSelection(nextIndex);`?

Comment: How to determine previous and next index? It is happening inside a button click and not a loop?

Comment: in determining sibling elements use how about using...array[ current_index -1 ] and array[ current_index +1 ]

Comment: Exactly - @krispymallows I ended up doing something similar, check my edit and suggest if you feel if its not appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use current index and use `setSelection` method like this:

```
public void showNext(View v){
    int nextIndex = sp.getSelectedItemPosition()+1;
    if(nextIndex < spItems.size())
    {   
        sp.setSelection(nextIndex);
    }
}
```

If you don't want to use `getSelectedItemPosition` directly, you can keep a global integer variable, `currentIndex`, and set it in `onItemSelected` method of spinner. And use that in button click method.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Let us consider `sp.getSelectedItemPosition()+1` is 1 and I want to switch to second element in the array list which has a value of 3. That is my spinner should have a selection of 3 (spin.setselection(3). In the case the above will fail. I dont want to switch sequentially from 1 to 2 to 3 and so forth I want to move the selection to the number at first index of list in onCreate() then on button click I want to set the selection to the second element of the list which can be 3,4,5,6 or nothing.

Comment: I don't think I am getting you. **I want to set the selection to the second element of the list which can be 3,4,5,6 or nothing.** and **I dont want to switch sequentially from 1 to 2 to 3 and so forth**. Can you be more clear?

Comment: Consider my list has [1][3][4] stored. In onCreate I set the selection to the first element in the list. spin.setSelection(list.get(1)). Now on Button click I want to detect the second element in the list, which is 3 and set my spinner to this value.

Comment: Firstly, be clear, you want to use INDEX or ITEM TEXT for setting new item? and what's requirement?

Comment: I did not specify ITEM TEXT anywhere in my question? I also tried to explain my requirement in the above comments and the question, please specify where you feel confused? I have list as [1][3][4] and these are positions I want to set to my spinner on button click.

Comment: Dear, u r not at all clear. `[1][3][4]` is text of item (ITEM TEXT), I guess.

Comment: How can position 2 not be there in arraylist?

Comment: That is the catch I am generating the array List dynamically and based on the element value I want to switch the position in the spinner. So in on create the spinner will be switched to the first element in the list that is 1 and on button click I want to switch the spinner to position 3 as that is the second element in the List.

Comment: DO U EVEN UNDERSTAND THE BASIC OF ARRAYLIST? HOW DO U SKIP ELEMENT 2?

Comment: Are you removing it? then ur element index 3 moves to 2/

Comment: Dudebro, I am not skipping elements in the arraylist. The Array list is at it is [1][3][4] and I want my spinner to switch positions from 1 to 3 to 4 as specified in the list. if the array list contained [4][5][7] I would switch my spinner from 4 to 5 to 7. The array list contains values which I want my spinner to switch to.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67699/discussion-between-magicalphoenix-and-user2822178).